# How can I find max and min number without using lists in Python?(user is going to write the numbers)

Tags: python

I am trying to find max and min number without using lists I know some information exist about this subject in here but mine is some different.I want numbers from the users.I am gonna continue to get the numbers until they enter -1.I could not find the solution.
Here is the code:

```
count=1
while count != -2:
    number=int(input("number:"))
    max=number
    min=number

if number != -1:
    count+=1
elif number == -1:
    if number > max:
        max = number
        print("max{}".format(max))
    if number < min:
        min = number
        print("min{}".format(min))
    break:
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a list?

Comment: Because this is the homework required of me.I need to do that with this way.

Comment: Start by not using max and min directly as they are native Python functions. Use something like `cur_max` and `cur_min`

Comment: @AdamJaamour is right. You should never uses builtin names as name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this. The idea is to remember only the max (or the min) value at each iteration to not use any list.

```
max_ = float('-inf')
min_ = float('inf')
while True:
    number=int(input("number:"))
    if number == -1:
        break
    else:
        # Without min and max function
        max_ = max_ if max_ > number else number
        min_ = min_ if min_ < number else number
        # max_ = max(max_, number)
        # min_ = min(min_, number)
print(f'Max: {max_}')
print(f'Min: {min_}')
```

Test:

```
number:10
number:5
number:8
number:3
number:-1
Max: 10
Min: 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I know about max and min function but I can not use this functions.I should write this manually.

Comment: I updated my answer but I'm pretty sure you could have found it by yourself :)

Comment: @stck_n. Does it solve your problem? You can check this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) or search for 'ternary operator' in python.

Comment: It is working.I appreciate for your answer:)

Comment: Glad to read that.